# Calculate time span in MVC Model using C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model in my MVC project that stores Activities. I need to display the difference between start time and end time.
Here is my model class:

```
[Table("DailyCrewActivity")]
public partial class DailyCrewActivity
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Crew Name")]
    [ForeignKey("DailyCrew")]
    public int daily_crew_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Task Number")]
    [ForeignKey("ContractTask")]
    public int contract_task_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Activity Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime activity_date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Activity Code")]
    public string activity_code { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
    public string activity_start { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
    public string activity_end { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Hours")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.##}")]
    public decimal ElapsedTime
    {
        get
        {
            decimal duration = 0;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(activity_start) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(activity_end))
            {

                TimeSpan spanStart;
                TimeSpan spanEnd;
                if (TimeSpan.TryParse(activity_start, out spanStart) && TimeSpan.TryParse(activity_end, out spanEnd))
                {
                    duration = Convert.ToDecimal(spanEnd - spanStart);
                }

            }
            return duration;
        }
    }

    public DailyCrew DailyCrew { get; set; }
    public ContractTask ContractTask { get; set; }

}
```

I am not getting a calculation returned to ElapsedTime. Is it because I am storing time in a string and then parsing it to TimeSpan?
I am not sure what it going on.

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(activity_start) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(activity_end)` didn't you miss the `!` (or `== false`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for both values to be null, which won't give you anything. You need to instead check for not empty/nulls on both:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(activity_start) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(activity_end))
{
    ...
}
```